# Sorting a list of strings by their components

Tags: python, list

A long list contains some elements to be sorted.

Actually each element has 4 contents: name, in/out, area and date&time, joined by ‘~’. (The ‘~’ can be changed.) I want to reorganize the list into a sorted order.

```
a_list = ["Chris~Check-in~Zoom A~11/13/2013 05:20",
"Chris~Check-in~Zoom G~11/15/2013 14:09",
"Frank E~Check-in~Zoom K~11/11/2013 08:48",
"Frank E~Check-in~Zoom K~11/15/2013 21:32",
"Kala Lu S~Check-in~Zoom N~11/13/2013 07:20",
"Milly Emily~Check-in~Zoom G~11/13/2013 01:08",
"Milly Emily~Check-in~Zoom E~11/16/2013 14:39",
"Milly Amy~Check-in~Zoom G~11/10/2013 20:14",
"Milly Amy~Check-in~Zoom A~11/16/2013 08:55",
"Milly Amy~Check-in~Zoom O~11/14/2013 21:57",
"Milly Amy~Check-in~Zoom A~11/15/2013 10:45",
"Nago Iko~Check-in~Zoom K~11/16/2013 20:42",
"Nago Iko~Check-in~Zoom K~11/14/2013 10:46",
"Liz D~Check-in~Zoom N~11/15/2013 01:46",
"Liz D~Check-in~Zoom A~11/12/2013 09:54",
"Liz D~Check-in~Zoom G~11/16/2013 13:15",
"Chris~Check-out~Zoom A~11/13/2013 13:42",
"Chris~Check-out~Zoom G~11/11/2013 14:21",
"Chris~Check-out~Zoom G~11/16/2013 09:41",
"Frank E~Check-out~Zoom K~11/14/2013 03:02",
"House P~Check-out~Zoom K~11/10/2013 11:17",
"Kala Lu S~Check-out~Zoom G~11/11/2013 23:27",
"Kala Lu S~Check-out~Zoom N~11/14/2013 11:17"]
```

It can be imported into MS Excel and sorted, but I am wondering if Python can do the job.

Would it be possible to sort them by the order in the list: 1. name, 2. date&time 3. area 4. in/out ?Like:

```
new_list = ["Chris~Check-out~Zoom G~11/08/2014 14:21",
"Chris~Check-in~Zoom A~11/10/2014 05:20",
"Chris~Check-out~Zoom A~11/10/2014 13:42",
"Chris~Check-in~Zoom G~11/12/2014 14:09",
"Chris~Check-out~Zoom G~11/13/2014 09:41",
"Frank E~Check-in~Zoom K~11/08/2014 08:48",
"Frank E~Check-out~Zoom K~11/11/2014 03:02",
"Frank E~Check-in~Zoom K~11/12/2014 21:32",
...
...]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the list, then sort with a custom `key` function. But you need to parse the date first to sort them correctly.

```
import datetime

new_l = sorted((x.split('~') for x in l),
               key=lambda x: (x[0],
                              datetime.datetime.strptime(x[3], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'),
                              x[2],
                              x[1]))
```

The key function returns a tuple. Tuples are compared lexicographically; the first items are compared; if they are the same then the second items are compared, and so on.<sup>[[1]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)</sup>

Alternatively, you can sort in stages. This will allow you to specify columns to sort by ascending or descending order individually.

```
from operator import itemgetter

nl = [x.split('~') for x in l]

nl.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
nl.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
nl.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[3], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'),
        reverse=True) # Newest first
nl.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

Keep in mind that both ways will make the new list split like this:

```
new_list = [["Chris", "Check-out", "Zoom G", "11/08/2014 14:21"], ...]
```

If you want to change them back to the original form you can `join` them:

```
new_list_joined = ['~'.join(x) for x in new_list]
```

Comment: I think it should be `x[0], x[3], x[2], x[1]`if you want to respect the OP's sort order.

Comment: Will the datetime sort correctly in that text format?

Comment: btw - you can use `itemgetter(0, 3, 2, 1)` to replace the lambda, if you prefer. `from operator import itemgetter`.

Comment: thanks, monkut. could you please post your answer so it can be shared by more for learning?

Comment: @monkut Ah, no it won't because of the date format (mm/dd/yyyy). I fixed it, thanks. But now I can't use itemgetter because it has to be parsed first.

Comment: Well done!  Yes, the extra parse step is a bit of a pain.  Mark if you have control of the text format it's good practice to format text dates in yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm so text sort can be applied.  `datetime_obj.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")`

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently sort the list of strings in-place by passing a key function to the its built-in`sort()` method. All the key function needs to do is return a tuple of values extracted from a single list item that is in the proper order and converted to the proper type for the comparison if necessary:

```
import datetime

def custom_sort(string_list):
    def key_func(s, strptime=datetime.datetime.strptime):
        s = s.split('~')
        return s[0], strptime(s[3], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), s[2], s[1]
    string_list.sort(key=key_func)

custom_sort(my_string_list)
```